# Installing existing purchase module with different name - OpenErp

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm trying to install the purchase app module from OpenErp with a different folder name, in order to edit code views as a different app and not modifying the existing one.

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 203, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1133, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1121, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 43, in proxy
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 31, in proxy_method
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 104, in send


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 90, in send
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 293, in dispatch_rpc
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 197, in execute
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 424, in button_immediate_install
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 475, in _button_immediate_function
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 218, in new
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 348, in load_modules
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 259, in load_marked_modules
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 162, in load_module_graph
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 133, in load_module
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\compra\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\compra\report\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\openerp\addons\compra\report\order.py", line 32, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\report\report_sxw.py", line 392, in __init__
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\report\interface.py", line 65, in __init__
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server\.\openerp\report\interface.py", line 45, in __init__
AssertionError: The report "report.purchase.order" already exists!
```

It throws me this error, could it be it's not possible to just change folder name and create new database without the existing purchase app installed to install it as another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the good way of customization. If you do so OpenERP will give you error about report already exists. You should make your own module for customization.

If you really don't want to make your own module then either you should remove remove all the reports or you should change the name of report in py and xml as well.

This will resolve your error.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, well it is more for learning purposes :) , but thank you very much, i'll do it that way.